# Web API call returns 'Unauthorized' message despite configuring JwtHelper in Angular UI

Tags: c#, angular, authentication, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a Web API written in `.net core 5.0` and I am using `Angular 10` for the front end. For now I have kept all the APIs open, however, to move this application in production I need to validate each API call and check if a logged in user is sending these requests.

I have modified the API controller like this :

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public List<ReportDataValues> GetReportingData()
{
   var ReportData = _context.ReportDataValues.ToList();
   return ReportData;           
}
```

Here is my relevant code for the `startup.cs` file which configures the JWT authentication :

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
   x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
   x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
   x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

   }).AddJwtBearer(x =>
    {
       x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
       x.SaveToken = false;
       x.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
       {
           ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
           IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(LoginKey),
           ValidateIssuer = true,
           ValidateLifetime = true,
           ValidIssuer = "https://localhost:5001",
           ValidAudience = "https://localhost:5001",                    
           ValidateAudience = true,
        };
   });
 }
```

I am using the `@auth0/angular-jwt` library to include authorization token in each http request. In my `app.module.ts` file I have declared a function :

```
export function tokenGetter(){
  return localStorage.getItem('token');
}
```

Here, token is the id for the key, where the server is returning the token value for the login request. I have verified that a token gets generated and is getting stored in the `localStorage`

In the `app.module.ts` I have also included the configuration to include the tokens in each request :

```
imports: [
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config : {
        tokenGetter : tokenGetter,
        allowedDomains : ["localhost:44326"],
        disallowedRoutes : []
      }
    }),
    BrowserModule,
    AutocompleteLibModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
```

Based on my understanding this should be enough to include the auth headers in each http request. Here is the http request I am making for this API controller :

```
 return this.http
      .get<any[]>(GlobalConstants.baseURL + 'ReportingData')
```

However, I get an error saying that this request is unauthorized and I see the Network tab in the dev tools has the Bearer token inside it and it is the same token that can be seen in the Application tab in dev tools:

[image]

The console logs this error as below :

[image]

Can someone please tell me if I need to make any other configuration changes to enable this request to be authorized?

Comment: 401 OK ?!?! Please share two things, Your production environment specifications. And a sample of your token

Comment: Hi @Amir, right now this code is running in my local env. The backend is running on Visual Studio and here's a sample of the token : eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2NjQ1NjUxMTcsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjUwMDEiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1MDAxIn0.5JMwnLta-6AycJOrFmUeZ0OMEHMpe7kKnWfhL4q0CuY

Comment: I guess you are reusing a token issued before. See this: 
{
  "exp": 1664565117,
  "iss": "https://localhost:5001",
  "aud": "https://localhost:5001"
}
The issuer of your token is https://localhost:5001, but you are requesting localhost:44326 in order to authorize

Comment: ok so I should modify my angular side allowedDomains : ["localhost:44326"], to allowedDomains : ["localhost:5001"]?

Comment: The main concept you should remember is to send JWT to a service that is the issuer of the JWT (It is true in your case) If you have any CORS errors, you should whitelist all of the origins you send request from (In angular and Server)

Comment: But what are the actual configurations of the authorization? Does it validate issuer? Does it validate audience? This part is missing in your question

Comment: added the code for the authentication configuration in startup.cs

Comment: It seems to be fixed based on your ValidIssuer and ValidAudience and sent token. Am I right?

Comment: unfortunately its still not fixed. Not sure what the problem might be